# Separate fields in R when no delimiter exists

Tags: r

I have a dataset like the following:

```
structure(list(Info = c("Acacia melanoceras 0.0369 0.0427 0.0267 0.0298 0.0501 0.0042 ", 
"Acalypha diversifolia van 0.0670 0.0439 0.0281 0.0427 0.0464 -0.0148 ", 
"Acalypha macrostachya vin 0.0657 0.0621 0.0441 0.0522 0.0473 -0.0173 ", 
"Adelia triloba 0.0481 0.0350 0.0202 0.0174 0.0286 -0.0349 ", 
"Aegiphila panamensis 0.0437 0.0312 0.0166 0.0148 0.0194 -0.0497 ", 
"Alchornea costaricensis 0.0568 0.0781 0.0502 0.0221 0.0734 -0.0153 "
)), .Names = "Info", row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

It currently has only one column and it looks like this

```
                                                                   Info
1         Acacia melanoceras 0.0369 0.0427 0.0267 0.0298 0.0501 0.0042 
2 Acalypha diversifolia van 0.0670 0.0439 0.0281 0.0427 0.0464 -0.0148 
3 Acalypha macrostachya vin 0.0657 0.0621 0.0441 0.0522 0.0473 -0.0173 
4            Adelia triloba 0.0481 0.0350 0.0202 0.0174 0.0286 -0.0349 
5      Aegiphila panamensis 0.0437 0.0312 0.0166 0.0148 0.0194 -0.0497 
6   Alchornea costaricensis 0.0568 0.0781 0.0502 0.0221 0.0734 -0.0153
```

I would like it to have 7 columns and look like this:

```
           Species             V1     V2      V3     V4    V5     V6
1         Acacia melanoceras 0.0369 0.0427 0.0267 0.0298 0.0501 0.0042 
2 Acalypha diversifolia van 0.0670 0.0439 0.0281 0.0427 0.0464 -0.0148 
3 Acalypha macrostachya vin 0.0657 0.0621 0.0441 0.0522 0.0473 -0.0173 
4            Adelia triloba 0.0481 0.0350 0.0202 0.0174 0.0286 -0.0349 
5      Aegiphila panamensis 0.0437 0.0312 0.0166 0.0148 0.0194 -0.0497 
6   Alchornea costaricensis 0.0568 0.0781 0.0502 0.0221 0.0734 -0.0153
```

This probelm has been giving me headaches as the species name is not always two words. The original text file is not delimited, so I have been unable to read it in delimited.  I have only been able to get it in as one column strings. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is the original file in a fixed width format? Do the numbers always start at a certain character? If so, `read.fwf()` could be helpful.

Comment: This was copied from a pdf file. I was unable to get ```read.fwf```,```fread```,```read.csv``` to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `gsub` for putting a comma before every number in the "Info" column of a dataframe we will assume is named "dat" and then re-read with read.csv:

```
> read.csv(text=gsub("( [-[:digit:].])", ",\\1", dat$Info), header=FALSE)
                         V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6      V7
1        Acacia melanoceras 0.0369 0.0427 0.0267 0.0298 0.0501  0.0042
2 Acalypha diversifolia van 0.0670 0.0439 0.0281 0.0427 0.0464 -0.0148
3 Acalypha macrostachya vin 0.0657 0.0621 0.0441 0.0522 0.0473 -0.0173
4            Adelia triloba 0.0481 0.0350 0.0202 0.0174 0.0286 -0.0349
5      Aegiphila panamensis 0.0437 0.0312 0.0166 0.0148 0.0194 -0.0497
6   Alchornea costaricensis 0.0568 0.0781 0.0502 0.0221 0.0734 -0.0153
```

I thank you for describing your use case. I might be able to use this myself in the future.

Comment: Many great answers...but I think this was especially elegant.  Thank you!

Comment: I learned this trick from @G.Grothendieck (a.k.a. user:516548). (And arguably learned regex in R from picking apart his answers on Rhelp to see what made them tick.) If you want to see really some elegant answers, he's the one to consult.

Comment: hey @BondedDust...I am trying to learn regex. Could you break down in English what you did here? Specifically, the ",\\1". I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose `ds` is your data:

```
ds <- 
  structure(list(Info = c("Acacia melanoceras 0.0369 0.0427 0.0267 0.0298 0.0501 0.0042 ", 
                          "Acalypha diversifolia van 0.0670 0.0439 0.0281 0.0427 0.0464 -0.0148 ", 
                          "Acalypha macrostachya vin 0.0657 0.0621 0.0441 0.0522 0.0473 -0.0173 ", 
                          "Adelia triloba 0.0481 0.0350 0.0202 0.0174 0.0286 -0.0349 ", 
                          "Aegiphila panamensis 0.0437 0.0312 0.0166 0.0148 0.0194 -0.0497 ", 
                          "Alchornea costaricensis 0.0568 0.0781 0.0502 0.0221 0.0734 -0.0153 "
  )), .Names = "Info", row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

You can then do something like

```
ds$Info <- gsub(" (-?[0-9])", ", \\1", ds$Info)
do.call(rbind, strsplit(ds$Info, ", "))
#     [,1]                        [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]      
#[1,] "Acacia melanoceras"        "0.0369" "0.0427" "0.0267" "0.0298" "0.0501" "0.0042 " 
#[2,] "Acalypha diversifolia van" "0.0670" "0.0439" "0.0281" "0.0427" "0.0464" "-0.0148 "
#[3,] "Acalypha macrostachya vin" "0.0657" "0.0621" "0.0441" "0.0522" "0.0473" "-0.0173 "
#[4,] "Adelia triloba"            "0.0481" "0.0350" "0.0202" "0.0174" "0.0286" "-0.0349 "
#[5,] "Aegiphila panamensis"      "0.0437" "0.0312" "0.0166" "0.0148" "0.0194" "-0.0497 "
#[6,] "Alchornea costaricensis"   "0.0568" "0.0781" "0.0502" "0.0221" "0.0734" "-0.0153 "
```

where `ds` is your data as above, you're nearly done. You first look for the space followed by a number and put in a comma. Then we split the strings and combine the vectors. You can then yourself convert the object to a `data.frame`, covert the relevant columns to `numeric`, and add `colnames`.

EDIT:
As seen in BondedDust's answer, using `read.csv` is much more elegant.

```
read.csv(text = ds$Info, header = FALSE)
```

Comment: Nice. You could also use `read.csv(text=ds$Info,header=FALSE)` instead of the `do.call(rbind, strsplit(...))` stuff which will avoid the need to do conversions of types.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion:

1) Split by `' '`, 
2) paste the species and genus names together (I assume you have 6 numeric columns) and 
3) make a (character) data.frame. 
4) Finally convert columns to numeric and 
5) set `Species` as colname.

```
    df <- structure(list(Info = c("Acacia melanoceras 0.0369 0.0427 0.0267 0.0298 0.0501 0.0042 ", 
                              "Acalypha diversifolia van 0.0670 0.0439 0.0281 0.0427 0.0464 -0.0148 ", 
                              "Acalypha macrostachya vin 0.0657 0.0621 0.0441 0.0522 0.0473 -0.0173 ", 
                              "Adelia triloba 0.0481 0.0350 0.0202 0.0174 0.0286 -0.0349 ", 
                              "Aegiphila panamensis 0.0437 0.0312 0.0166 0.0148 0.0194 -0.0497 ", 
                              "Alchornea costaricensis 0.0568 0.0781 0.0502 0.0221 0.0734 -0.0153 "
)), .Names = "Info", row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
df

# split
sp <- strsplit(df$Info, ' ')
sp

# make (character) data.frame
require(plyr)
newdf <- ldply(sp, function(x) {
  l <- length(x)
  dta <- x[(l-5):l]
  spec <- paste(x[1:(l-6)], collapse = ' ')
  out <- c(spec, dta)
  return(out)
})

# make numeric cols
newdf[ , 2:7] <- apply(newdf[ , 2:7], 2, function(x) as.numeric(x))
names(newdf)[1] <- 'Species'
str(newdf)
```